# Is it possible to dump a log file into a database?

Tags: logging, mysql, logfile

I'm working on a project with an application that stores its logs in a flat file.

The logs however also need to be stored in a mysql database for monitoring purposes.

Is it possible to create a database using a log file as input? So I guess it would be the reverse of a mysqldump?

Comment: They're already stored in a database that has been optimised for file storage and retrieval: your filesystem.  Why do you want to store them in an RDBMS, exactly?  What are these "*monitoring purposes*" to which you allude?

Comment: As part of the requirements the system needs to log to a flat file and I need them in a mysql database. Tools will be used to analyze the data in the mysql database. I'm not sure what these tools are

Comment: "*I need them in a MySQL database*" probably requires some further explanation.  What is the schema of this database?  It will probably be determined by the analysis that is to be performed, or the tools that are to manipulate it.  That in turn will dictate how the logs can be imported.

Comment: Just parse the log file and write it to a database using a schema that's going to make it easy to 'monitor' - or just 'monitor' the log file.

Comment: The format of the db doesn't matter right now. I'm a noob with databses and just wanted to know if what I need to do would be possible

Comment: so dont dump file ,create a separate function for updating log message to db ,with time stamp

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. There are a million ways to do this, here is one using bash with sqlite3 as the database.

```
dw2:/tmp$ echo 'create table log (datetime string, message varchar(255));' | sqlite3 test.db
dw2:/tmp$ cat test.log
2013-01-16 05:24:40-05:00 Log line 1
2013-01-16 05:24:42-05:00 Log line 2
2013-01-16 05:24:44-05:00 Log line 3
2013-01-16 05:24:46-05:00 Log line 4
dw2:/tmp$ while read date time logmsg; do 
    echo "insert into log values ('$date $time', '$logmsg');" | sqlite3 test.db
done < test.log
dw2:/tmp$ echo 'select * from log;' | sqlite3 test.db                           
2013-01-16 05:24:40-05:00|Log line 1
2013-01-16 05:24:42-05:00|Log line 2
2013-01-16 05:24:44-05:00|Log line 3
2013-01-16 05:24:46-05:00|Log line 4
```